# New LightSwitch Project

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have started a new Lightswitch project using a SQL database that was created with Lightswitch.  When I publish and install the new Desktop project everything goes fine with no errors in publishing, installing or loading the new application. The first and only screen appears. I can click on different records and the data shows up and I can edit the data.  However, if I use the list search function all of the fields get Red x'd.
The original application works the way it supposed to work.
I have tried with and without IIS: Published with (local) and (IIS) and get the same results with both methods.
The connecection string options for the new app are not the same as the original in that System Admin and Sytem user connecection strings are not offered so it is difficult to know if I replicating a working setup or not.
In Mananagement Studio I am awash in security, permissions, roles, and login selecitons.  It seems clear that this is permission level problem but I have no idea on where to start trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

see:
Diagnosing Problems in a Deployed 3-Tier LightSwitch Application 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/09/20/diagnosing-problems-in-a-deployed-lightswitch-application-eric-erhardt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How many string properties are in the table that you're displaying? Is there a large number of properties that don't need to be included in the search?

This forum post discusses the same issue as you're encountering: [Search returns error "Unable to load data" with a Red X](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/c8acb1d1-49de-4231-908c-962a49117de4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your connection string setup? I do have those issues back when I was using SQL Express on development and using SQL Server Enterprise as my target database server.